# Encoding special float values in json

Tags: json, floating-point

Is there a suggested practice for encoding the following three values in JSON?

- `NaN`
- `Infinity`
- `+Infinity`

For example, should they just be encoded as-is as strings? Should `NaN` be converted to `null` instead? What is the suggested practice for encoding these values?